# Question about using glVertexAttribArray

Tags: opengl, c++

After defining an attribute pointer, why can't I just reuse it? I have a VAO bound so shouldn't it just accept the AttributePointer I defined with the last VAO?

```
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    unsigned int VBO;
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertecies), vertecies, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    unsigned int EBO;
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indicies), indicies, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindVertexArray(0);


    //Second Cordinates
    glBindVertexArray(VAO2);

    unsigned int VBO2;
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO2);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO2);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertecies2), vertecies2, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    unsigned int EBO2;
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO2);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO2);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indicies2), indicies2, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    //glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

So... after a little more reading I found out that VertexAttributePointer is stored per VAO...